# copy files from container on to another server in gitlabci

Tags: docker, copy, containers, gitlab-ci

am inside a docker alphine linux container which is running on a different host and need to copy a file into another windows server machine or linux server machine.

wont be able to get the name of the container as am inside the container while running,and container is created dynamincally.

am inside the gitlab-ci script and trying to run the script from inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you transfer the file/artifact to some intermediary storage service like an S3 bucket?  If you're running on-prem only then some intermediary file server.

Without knowing more I can only suggest using something like sftp or rsync to move the file somewhere reasonable.  Then fetch said file from the destination.